# how to call context menu from context menu

Tags: java, android, class, methods

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int selecteditemid = item.getItemId();
         switch(selecteditemid){
               case R.id.rajasthan:
                   // I want to call context menu from here
                   break;
               case R.id.gujrat:
                   break;
               case R.id.maharastra:
                   break;
            }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I want context menu from these items of context menu, i also tried `onCreateContextMenu()` function but it didn't worked.

Comment: "It didn't work"; it's best to put the results of things you have tried in the body of the question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, what have you tried, specifically? Debugging is a critical skill for any coder. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Tried to make the question clearer...